# How to switch between login and logout using access token in react native

Tags: react-native, access-token, asyncstorage

How to fetch logout api using async storage and how to remove access token. If I logout from home page, it should move to login page.

```
async onDelete() {
    let access_token = this.state.accessToken

    try {
        let response = await fetch('my url', {
            method: 'GET',
        });
        let res = await response.text();

        if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
            console.log("success sir: " + res)
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
            let error = res;
        } else {
            throw error;
        }
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("error: " + error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you'll fetch your api:

```
fetch(yourLogoutApi, { method: "GET" })
.then(response => response.json())
.then(responseJson => {//do something with responseJson if you want to})
.catch(error => {console.error(error);});
```

And to remove your access token use `AsyncStorage.removeItem('yourtokenKEY');` and then navigate to Login Screen using `this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');`